# How to use more than one data sources in JPA

Tags: jpa

I want to use two data sources at same time and use them based on the condition.
Can I add multiple data sources in *persistence.xml* like:

```
<jta-data-source>gov/v3/jdbc/dataSource1</jta-data-source>
<jta-data-source>gov/v3/jdbc/dataSource2</jta-data-source>
```

Please send your suggestion.

Note: Application server is weblogic 10.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure multiple datasources in your *persistence.xml* this way:

```
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit name="persistence-unit-1">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/persistence-unit-1</jta-data-source>
    ...
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="persistence-unit-2">
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/persistence-unit-2</jta-data-source>
     ...
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Use these datasources from your application as follows:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit-1");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what "condition"?

EclipseLink does support data partitioning, not sure if this is what you are looking for.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Data_Partitioning