# EntityManager in JNDI

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I need to use different databases in the same Web application, so I can't use a persistent.xml to define the target database. The database changes with the client which is connected.
I found this :

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (em == null}
        try{
            em = (EntityManager)(new InitialContext())
                                        .lookup("java:comp/ejb/EntityManager");
        } catch (Exception e){};
    }
    return em;
}
```

at this URL : http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI

My question is now : how recording a EntityManager or a Persistence Unit in the JNDI of GlassFish ?

Comment: Where did you get this idea: _I need to use different databases in the same Web application, so I can't use a persistent.xml_? Just declare multiple persistence units with different names. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5587671/6413377) for example. Assuming that _persistent.xml_ is really **persistence.xml**?

Comment: Yes, but each time I have a new client, I will have to modify persistence.xml and I'll have to redeploy my application ?  If yes, I am not sure that it's the best solution :-(, if no it's a great solution :-)

Comment: Ok so I misunderstood it so that one instance of web app uses two dbs at the _same time_.  But your problem is then that that you deploy the app to different servers with different dbs with different configurations?

Comment: Hi, I tested your solution, it works fine except for Transactions, they are not managed correctly, in fact they are not managed at all, I'm going to give up this solution ! Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that my `persistence.xml` is:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

 <persistence-unit  name="ctx-vendor" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

We have two use case:

[WAR application `WEB-INF/web.xml` file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/servjndi010.htm):

```
<persistence-context-ref>
  <description>JNDI for lookup EntityManager</description>
  <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/ctx-vendor</persistence-context-ref-name>
  <persistence-unit-name>ctx-vendor</persistence-unit-name>
  <persistence-context-type>Transaction</persistence-context-type>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

[EAR application `META-INF/application.xml` file:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/usclient005.htm#CIHFIDHI)

```
<application xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd"
  version="7">
  <description>My Vendor System</description>
  <display-name>vendor-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>vendor-rest.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/vendor-rest</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>vendor-service.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
  <persistence-context-ref>
    <description>JNDI for lookup EntityManager</description>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>persistence/ctx-vendor</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>ctx-vendor</persistence-unit-name>
    <persistence-context-type>Transaction</persistence-context-type>
  </persistence-context-ref>
</application>
```

Stateless Session Bean

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "persistence/ctx-vendor", unitName = "ctx-vendor")
public class BaseFacade
{ }

@Stateless
@Local(CatalogFacade.class)
public class CatalogFacadeImpl extends BaseFacade implements CatalogFacade
{
}
```

Tested in Glassfish 4.1